# Access to protected member and properties case

Tags: c#, oop

I have one base class called Cocpit for Server and Protocl derived classes then I have Heartbeatsupervisorclass which would take Server and protocol and do some work anyway I got some problem with access to protected member inside Heartbeat - I know because I am trying to access through Server object and not over heartbeat but how to solve that issue according to my whole code?

CHANGED

```
public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
        {

         Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
        options.DontFragment = true;
        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        try
        {
          PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(HOST, timeout, buffer, options);
          if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
          {            
            //Ping was successful
            return true
          }
          else
```

Answer (score 3):

> and after all when want to use inside Heartbeate I cant access protocol.Name inside constructor - how to access that?

You can't, while it's protected. `protected` is designed to give access to protected members of objects of type `Foo` (and derived classes) within `Foo`.

From section 3.5.3 of the C# 5 specification:

> When a protected instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it is declared, and when a protected internal instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, the access must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared. Furthermore, the access is required to take place through an instance of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it. This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing protected members of other derived classes, even when the members are inherited from the same base class.

It sounds like you should probably just make `Name` a public property. It's not clear why these are all virtual, mind you... and some could be more concisely implemented as automatically implemented properties, too.

Comment: Cocpit gives Name and Id to derived clasess virtul because from begining i dont know whether derived classes would need to do some calculation so it would need to additioanl setter deployment they can just use it or implement by themselves if required to do some additional value control inside setter. I know that I cant do that but I am looking approach how to rebuilt this app to be working as hearbeat is not within inheritance from Cocpit and want to take Server and Protocol and do some calculation how this all should be changed to achieve?

Comment: @nighttrain: It's not really clear what you mean, but you could try just making the *getter* public but have a protected *setter*.

Comment: What I want to achieve is my class heartbeatsupervisor would use Server and Protocol and take them values to do some calculation let say:
Server sr = new Server("127.0.0.1");
Protocol pr = new Protocol("tcp");
then Heartbeatsupervisor would take those two
and use their values inside some method to lets say make a ping.

Comment: @nighttrain: So (for the third time) it sound like you need to make the `Name` property publicly readable (and `Server.Ip`, too).

Comment: @nighttrain: No, I don't have time right now - but it's *really* simple. You have a protected property - make it a public property. If you want to make the setter protected, you can do that. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx for more details.

Comment: I rechanged my code and put it inside first post below RECHANGED - please see now.

Comment: @nighttrain: Well now the *setter* is public too - is that what you want? Also you `Server.Ip` property could be autoimplemented. If you want a full code review, you should go to codereview.stackexchange.com - but it looks like this should at least have solved the question you asked.

Comment: I rechanged my code and put it inside first post below RECHANGED - please see now.

Comment: @nighttrain: You haven't made any change since my previous comment. Why did you repeat your comment?

Comment: I will go this link - please See now in REACHANGED VER 2 ( if you mean protected inside Heartbeat its ok within this implementation its working as in Program clas. I am carry about my Properties way of implementation.

P.S Do you know som good example of class structure within some program - not only Animal :) as it is only basic some more extended where some classes not under inheritance using completely different classes I would like to see how properties and other things are implemented on good example.

Comment: This is now a *long* way off the topic of the question. Asking follow-up questions in comments is discouraged in Stack Overflow. (I do note that you *still* haven't paid attention to my suggestion of using automatically implemented properties more widely though.)